# How do you filter or search a nested list in q

Tags: kdb

Say I have a list

```
list:(`a`b;`ac`d;`e`af)
```

and I want to search for all symbols like `a` to give

```
(`a;`ac;`af)
```

How would I go about it?

If I try and use

```
list where each list like "*c*"
```

(which without each works for a flat list) I get a `type` error

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is almost there - `like` works fine with flat lists, but needs to be told to operate on each element of the left argument:

```
q)list like\:"*c*"
00b
10b
00b
```

you can then use `where each` and apply back to each element of the initial list with each-both (`'`):

```
q)list@'where each list like\:"*c*"
`symbol$()
,`ac
`symbol$()
```

This returns only the elements matching the `like` right argument in each element, so there are empty lists returned.

Answer (score 2):

As you are looking for *any* occurrence and it seems you don't care about the position, you can just use `raze` here. It gives you your desired results.

```
q)list:(`a`b;`ac`d;`e`af)
q){r where (r:raze x) like y}[list;"a*"]
`a`ac`af
```